# Where to put live chat?

Tags: layout, chat, live

We are considering putting live chat on our website to be able to help our customers when they need. Now we are deciding where to put it. Usually they are location on the right bottom corner, or they pinned to the right/left side somewhere in the middle.

Do you have any recommendations on where to put it and why?

Comment: Like with almost any UX Problem, understanding the context is key to solving the problem. Before recommending anything, I would ask about how users enter the site? Do they navigate from the home or is there an entry point via Google? Is the site all about (selling) products or does it feature other things like services as well? What do you know about the people this feature targets? Do they have an account and do they use it? In short: I think there is no best way to implement chat. Eg: chat on Amazon will be very different from chat on a Mercedes site.

Comment: I am asking only about the location.

Comment: And my humple opinion is that for answering that question, you really need an answer on most of the questions I asked. I could say 'at the bottom right' because nearly all websites do that. But if your site is a webshop with either the shopping cart at the bottom right (not common) or the CTA at the bottom right (very common) it's bad advice. Or maybe your users need to navigate while chatting and a separate window would be the best solution. If there was a recipe for best site in the world, we would be out of a job pretty fast ;-)

Comment: Ok. Users navigate to the page from Navigation bar at the top mostly. Site is selling services, which are quite difficult to understand and has a lot of little details. Sometimes they do have an account, but most likely they won't. Site is not a webshop and it doesn't have a cart. Of course, we are not going to cover any important elements with the chat. Any other answers you need to know?

Answer (score 2):

You say the services are quite difficult to understand... I think that's the place where the chat should go. I have no idea how that page looks, but I imagine a page with some global easy-to-understand-information at the top and the further the user goes to the bottom the more detailed and technical the page will become.

In this situation I could think of a few places where to put the chat.

1. At the start of the detailed information. Since this is the place things will get technical, chances are that visitors will start to have questions about the information that is shown to them. Left, right? I think the design dictates this e.g. what is logical in this situation?
2. Triggered event at scroll
   You could also choose for a fixed button somewhere along the side that shows after the visitor scrolls down. An advantage with this implementation is that it appears "out of nothing" and will therefor be noticed by most users. It can, however, also be experienced as annoying (especially on mobile).

Comment: I think every business with a chat should have the goal that the chat is used as less as possible. First you know firsthand whst people bugs and what they dont understand so you can change it. Second you have less people chatting with you which reduces costs and provides you with the ability to provide better support for the individual